# What does it mean "It’s raining men"?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

What does it mean "It’s raining men"?  I got this in this paragraph:

> Metaphor - Describing something by using a word that isn’t literally
> relevant. For example, “It’s raining men”, “I’m feeling blue”, or “The
> weather was bitterly cold”.

Comment: It means ([in the song](https://youtu.be/eiUEmYbCVak?t=36)) that there are so men to choose from, blonde, dark and mean that the lucky (??) woman  can have her pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the 'not literally relevant' word is *raining* - rather than *men*. The phrase comes from the Gloria Gaynor song of the same title and describes a situation in which a single girl might go out and have the opportunity to meet a large number of eligible men. An analogous phrase might be '*it's raining money*'.

Comment: The song "It's Raining Men" was not by Gloria Gaynor - it was by the group [The Weather Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weather_Girls) (in fact, the duo changed their name to The Weather Girls because of the success of this song).  Gloria Gaynor is best known for "I Will Survive", a different disco song from the same era.